# How to set login page as start page in mvc application?

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

I am using mvc application. I want to add a login page for my mvc application. I created a login.cshtml file for login form (it contains user name and password). When I run the project, it starts with the home page. I want to start with login page. How can I achieve this?

Comment: are you using .net core or mvc5?

Comment: I am using mvc5

Comment: @NivithaG the best solution is the one of Zaheer Ul Hassan. That is how I would have done it as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to `App_Start` folder in your solution and open `RouteConfig.cs` and replace this method with your code:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Hope it help you!

Comment: @NivithaG try this solution

Comment: Thanks. It is useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

1. Right-click your Project within the Solution Explorer.   Choose
   Properties.
2. Select the Web tab on the left-hand side.
3. Under the **Start Action** section, define the **Specific Page** you would
   like to default    to when the application is launched.
4. Save your changes.

Answer (score 1):

Answering because I had the same question. My code looked like this in the startup.cs

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        });
```

I changed the name of the controller and index to the controller and index i wanted it to call to.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Login}/{action=Register}/{id?}");

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

I just saw this is for MVC3. Maybe it helps someone else.

Original:

In your global.asax file there is a default route specified in the RegisterRoutes function:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Site", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Just change the parameters.

To keep people from entering the site without logging in you have to keep track of the user's login status, e.g. in the user session, and check it whenever an action is being called.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `HomeController.cs` and just replace the

```
public ActionResult Index()       
{
  return View();      
}
```

with

```
public ActionResult Index()       
{
  return View("Login");     
}
```

For this to work, your `login.cshtml` should be in the `Views/Home` folder.
If it is inside another folder, then try this:

```
public ActionResult Index()       
{
  return View("~/Views/YourFolderName/Login.cshtml");     
}
```